# How to bind ng-click to a event handler defined inside directive?

Tags: angularjs

All:

I define a directive like:

```
.directive("hellobutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.sayhello = function(){
                 console.log("hello");
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I wonder how can I use that sayhello handler on this directive like:

```
<hellobutton ng-click="sayhello()"></hellobutton>
```

Basically I do not want to pass sayhello from outter scope but let this directive internal scope to handle it.

I wonder is it possible or I have to define that handler inside a template?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a function as a parameter:

```
.directive("hellobutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
          callback: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.callback();
        }
    }
})
```

and

```
<hellobutton callback="sayhello()"></hellobutton>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not quite get ur point, do you mean we have to pass that sayhello() from outter scope?

Comment: To add to OP's comment: Explain what you've done and why.  It's unclear.  I like to put comments in the code to point out what I've done differently and what it does to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just define the directive with a link function and bind to the click event. It can then be attached to any element. See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ogd1YFZbt4tWJ5ckY4bl?p=preview)

JS:

```
app.directive("hellobutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
          elem.on('click', function() {
            console.log("hello");
          })
        }
    }
})
```

Markup:

```
<button type="button" hellobutton="">Click Me, I'm a button</button>
<div hellobutton="">Click me too, I'm a DIV</div>
```